# Access JSON files in a JavaScript and HTML application

Tags: javascript, html, json, internationalization, xampp

I want to implement i18n in my application, which is written in HTML and JavaScript, with PHP as the backend. I have a JSON file, with all the keys and translations. Since I've read that JSON files cannot be read from local storage, where would I store these JSON files, on XAMPP, so I can access them in my app? Also, can I directly access them using JavaScript, or would I need to use PHP?

Thank you

Comment: You can `ajax` that json file..

Comment: You can use java-script. ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
        url: url +"//jsonfile.txt",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data, status) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
            jsondata = jsonObject;
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! So is this to be added in the JS file? Also, since I have a `.json` file, would I need to keep `dataType: 'JSON'`?

Comment: Yes dataType should be json.. also you have to import jQuery : http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Another method using jQuery,,,,     http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Which folder in Xampp should I store the JSON file in, so that it is considered a server side file?

Comment: you can keep it inside a folder in your website directory.. Later you can restrict access using htaccess file.

Comment: `$.getJSON( "en.json", function( data ) {
    console.log(data.age);
   });`

This is my code within the `script` tags in the html file, but this is not working. The "en.json" file is in the htdocs folder of xampp. Thank you!